# Overflow: hidden + line-height — как подружить?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет
столкнулся с проблемой, есть верстка, 3 дива, на 1 из них overflow: hidden, из-за чего едет базовая линия контейнера.
как выровнять блоки в одну линию? Пример верстки добавил сюда: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ap11fxod/1/

```css
.a {
  height: 29px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #f231ad;
  line-height: 29px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.a > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.b {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 370px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.c {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.d {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ
  </div>
  <div class='c'>
    Текст 1
  </div>
  <div class='d'>
    Текст 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как минимум не семантично писать текст в дивах, сделай для начала норм розметку...

Comment: `.a > div {
  display: inline-block;
}`

забери инлайн блок и поставь `float: left;`

Answer (score 1):

Все просто.

```
.a {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
.a {
  height: 29px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #f231ad;
  line-height: 29px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
}
.a > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.b {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 370px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.c {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.d {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШОЙ ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ
  </div>
  <div class='c'>
    Текст 1
  </div>
  <div class='d'>
    Текст 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант — добавить `vertical-align` к внутренним блокам:

```
.a > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

`bottom` можно заменить на что-то другое по желанию. Блоки со свойством `inline-block` с помощью `vertical-align` выравниваются в строке друг относительно друга по высоте своими границами.